# Improper Integrals as Equivalence class

Tags: integration

I've heard today for the first time that supposedly the "most precise" way to define improper integrals is to view them as an equivalence class as follows:

$\int f(x) dx = F(x) + c$

whereas F(x) is to be understood as:

$F_{1} \sim F_{2} \leftrightarrow \exists c \in \mathbb R: F_{1} - F_{2} = c$

[F] = {$F_{1} \in C^{1}((a,b)) \mid F_{1} - F + c \in \mathbb R$ }

Are these sets (improper integrals and the set defined via the equivalence relationship) indeed equivalent?

Comment: Hey, I think that you're refering to indefinite integrals here

Comment: Also, you might wanna check out that set, and look at the relation. Also, there's a subtle, pedantic point that's not worth mentioning.

Comment: I am not english native so I don't know if its "improper" or "indefinite". What is the subtle point you are refering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see this is to generalize this far beyond this point:

> **Theorem.** Let $f\colon A\to B$ be some function between two sets, then the relation $x\sim y\iff f(x)=f(y)$ is an equivalence relation on $A$.

The proof is not very difficult, and it is a good exercise in equivalence relations. I will leave this part for you.

Now we use the fundamental theorem of calculus: $$(F(x)+c)'=\left(\int f dx\right)' = f$$

So now consider the map $F\mapsto F'$, on the domain $C^1((a,b))$ (so it is well-defined). The equivalence class is exactly the induced by this map:

$$F-G = C\iff (F-G)'=0\iff F'=G'$$

Comment: So, in case of the generalization we have an equivalence class just because "=" on a set itself is an equivalence relation. Thanks for this very good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For any function $F(x)$ for which $F'(x)=f(x)$, we also know that $(F(x)+c)'=F'(x)+(c)'=F'(x)=f(x)$.  The converse is given by the fundamental theorem of calculus.  So, we can view all such functions as equivalent under the $\sim$ relation you've given.