# Where is the mistake in this false proof using indefinite integral?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, fake-proofs

Indefinite integral of a function $f$, i.e $\int f(x)dx$ gives as result a infinite amount of functions such that $F'(x) = f(x)$ that differs by a constant called integration constant($C$), that is $\int f(x)dx = F(x) +C$

Also integral satisfies the property $\int f(x)+g(x)dx=\int f(x)dx + \int g(x)dx$

Using the indefinite definition and that property i can do the following procedure:

$$\int f(x)dx = \int f(x)dx$$
$$\int f(x)dx = \int f(x)+0 dx$$
$$\int f(x)dx = \int f(x)dx + \int 0dx$$
$$\color{red}{\int f(x)dx } = \color{red}{\int f(x)dx} + C_1, \text{with } C_1 \in \mathbb{R}$$
$$\color{red}{F(x)+C}=\color{red}{F(x)+C} + C_1$$
$$0=C_1$$

And since $C_1$ can take any real value we can have

$$0=1$$.

And i want to know, where is the mistake?

Comment: The very first line is incorrect. Indefinite integrals aren't equal

Comment: @Eduardo Sebastian This question points to an important conceptual issue which lies at a very fundamental level: the indefinite integral of a function $f$ (which has primitives) should be rigorously defined as *the set of all primitives* of the given function $f$. In this acceptation, the indefinite integral of $f$ becomes an affine line within the ambient vector space of all functions defined on the definition domain of $f$ and with numeric values (that is, codomain $\mathbb{R}$). The error of the calculations set forth above vanishes once one assumes this correct definition.

Comment: @SoumyadwipChanda in what sense do you mean? as Lorenzo's answer said, they are equal in its equivalence class

Answer (score 4):

Good question!

The problem has to do with vague language about what $\int f(x) dx + C$ means. It is not a particular function, but an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of functions, where two functions are equivalent **iff** they differ by a constant **iff** their derivatives are equal.

Unfortunately, that's not the most readable wikipedia page if you are unfamilair with this notion -- perhaps you can [look here](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Mathematical_Reasoning__Writing_and_Proof_(Sundstrom)) or at any 'introduction to mathematical proofs' kind of text. For now, you can think of it as a partitioning of the set of all functions into sets of 'equivalent functions,' where two functions are equivalent if they have the same derivative. An equivalence relation on a set is essentially the same notion as a partition of a set, so there's nothing lost by taking this point of view.

In particular, $0$ and $1$ refer to the same equivalence class, namely that of all constant functions. There is no contradiction, but you have understand that when you write equality between two such indefinite integrals you mean an equality between the corresponding equivalence classes.

Picking a value for $C$ amounts to choosing a representative for an equivalence class; and it is not contradiction to say that two equal equivalence classes have representatives that are not equal.

As the comments point out, the confusion at various points in your calculation will disappear when you define the indefinite integral this way. It's really a problem of ambiguity that will disappear when you internalize the correct definition.

For the calculus student, usually the end goal of indefinite integration is to do a definite integration. When you use the fundamental theorem of calculus to compute $\int_a^b f(x) dx$, as long you use the same value of $C$ for both endpoints then *any* choice of $C$ will give the same answer. So this is why intro calculus courses typically tell students to 'pick any C' -- but, as you've discovered, this can be conceptually misleading.

(This also explains why students get docked for not writing $+C$ -- a decision that would make more sense if we told them it was there to indicate that one was thinking of the equivalence class, and not a particular function...)

Also, you can shorten your paradox by considering $F(x) + C = \int f(x) dx = F(x) + C'$.

(See here for some further discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306927/54092 )

Comment: Thank you very much. If I start working with integrals, and eliminate the integrals (as in my example) the equation will always remain an equality between equivalence classes? Or is there any way to remove that? Apparently deriving both sides is a way to go from "equality between equivalence classes" to the "classic equality" that is known in pre-calculus (I don't know how it's called)

Comment: Also, i read some answer in MSE [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1018982) who say I cannot subtract integrals. But with your answer I think that I can since we are working with equivalence classes.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian There is more structure to this equivalence relation; in particular, you can add and subtract equivalence classes, and multiply them by scalars. This is because if $f, \tilde{f}$ are equivalent, and $g, \tilde{g}$ are equivalent, then $f + g, \tilde{f} + \tilde{g}$ are equivalent, as are $f - g$ and  $\tilde{f} - \tilde{g}$. Additionally, if $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, then $\alpha f$ and $\alpha \tilde{f}$ are equivalent. You can verify this using either definition of equivalence. This is the relevant concept: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(linear_algebra)

Comment: I think the reason that calculus students are told not to subtract indefinite integrals is because no notation or concept is introduced in their class for "the equivalence class of all functions with the same derivative as $f$," and without this concept doing algebra on equivalence classes can lead to confusion.

Note also that the only algebra you can do on these equivalence classes is addition and subtraction. You can check that you cannot multiply them by multiplying representatives, for instance. (Unlike, say, modular arithmetic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic.)

Comment: So, $\alpha  \int f(x)dx = \int f(x)dx, \text{ with } \alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ is also true, according to equivalence relation?

Comment: Regarding my first question of the comments, I mean how can I "get rid" of the equality between class of equivalences and continue working with a "classic" equality. I realized that when I derive both sides of the equation, then the equation becomes a "classic" equation where 0 = 1 is not true and where I can perform the operations like exponentiation, division, etc.So my question was, is deriving both sides of the equation is the only way to do this? I mean, deriving is the only way to get rid of [modulo constants](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/807700)?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian No, that formula is not true. Multiplying by $\alpha$ changes the equivalence class,  but it preserves equality of two equivalence classes if you do it to both of them.

Comment: Regarding the other part: Think about the analogy with modular arithmetic; in that case, there is a natural set of representatives, namely $0,1,2,...,p-1$ for the equivalence classes. However, I would be very careful here. For instance, 2^2 = 1 mod 3, but if you pick representatives sloppily, you might end up falsely concluding that 2^2 = 1  over the integers. For integration, you can pick the representative $F$ with $F(0) = 0$ and have a set of representatives that are compatible with + and scaling.

Comment: There are infinitely many ways to pick such representatives. It essentially amounts to picking a complement to the 1-dimensional subspace consisting of constant functions. You can check that every function can be written as a sum of a constant function and a function satisfying $F(0) = 0$. This always happens when you look at a vector space modulo another vector space. The reason you can't get such an analogous thing for modular arithmetic is because $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't decompose in the same way. I think studying some abstract algebra will clear up a lot of these questions (which are great).

Answer (score 0):

Derivative of a constant is zero.

$C$ is a constant, and  $C+C_1$ is an another constant

It will give different constants without a certain $(x;y)$ point

$$g_1(x)=\int f(x)dx \not= \int f(x)dx=g_2(x)$$ their primitive function are not equal